# Weird data lose in javascript while converting Array into Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I was just working with JavaScript objects and found this which i cant figure out . I created an array with few values and trying to convert that array into object using spread and new in JavaScript but for my surprise only the first value in the array is been put into the object with its type .

I have no need what exactly is happening in background

```
let array = [1970,1,1]
let object = new Object(array)

console.log(object)
```

Output :

```
Number {1970}
```

> I was expecting {1970 , 1 , 1} object but actual output is
>   Number {1970}

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in Chrome 75.0.

Comment: "*trying to convert that array into object*" - what? An array object already is an object. So what do you actually want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to convert array  to object use  Object.assign

```
Object.assign({},[1970,1,1])
```

or you can populate the object with the array elements

```js
let array = [1970,1,1];
var obj = new Object();
Array.prototype.push.apply(obj, array);
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Can you tell me whats up with my approach why all other values expect the first is discarded

Comment: you cannot use array as constructor for  Object , to fix your approach, you should use  let obj = new Object(); Array.prototype.push.apply(obj, array);

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing you could do is:

```
const object = {...array}
```

Which will give you the output:

```
{0: 1970, 1:1, 2:1}
```

Comment: Yes. Can you tell me what is wrong with my approach

Comment: In general you should avoid using the literal constructor `new Object`. If you pass an array to it will just return the array back.

Comment: when using the spread operator  `const obj  = {...array}` you are telling: Hey make me an object with a property for each item of this array, and this property name will be the element's index

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
let array = [1970,1,1];
let object = Object.assign({}, array);
console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

It works in the Chrome (Version 75).

Check the following code, if in case you are expecting the following behavior.

**CODE:**

```js
let array = [1970,1,1];
let obj = {}, i = 0;
for(var element in array) obj[i++] = array[element];
console.log(obj);
```